# PUT request with data using AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, put, afnetworking-2

I want to upload video using PUT request and this is my experience.

I was trying many possibilities of doing PUT request using AFNetworking 2.0, but everything fails.

But I resolved this and this "Question" is information for everybody else who is asking solution.

This works for me:

```
NSDictionary *headersDict = @{@"Content-Length": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", mySize], @"Content-Type": @"video/mp4", @"Accept": @"application/json", @"Authorization": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", hash]};

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:urlToPut];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
[request setHTTPBody:videoData];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headersDict];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // if everything run great, we have to invalidate timer to notify
    [uploadTimer invalidate];

}
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@",  error);
}];

// start timer where app will be checking upload progres on the server
uploadTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(checkUploadProgressForRecord:)
                                       userInfo:record
                                        repeats:YES];

[operation start];
```

**Anybody has another solution?**

Answer (score 0):

You approach has the following issues:

1. The PUT method is not the suggested method for uploading a file. PUT *can* be used, but this requires that the server MUST create the resource at the *specified* URI. In most cases however, the server will create a new URI (which is unknown to the client) when saving the uploaded file locally on the server. In this case, a POST method must be used.
2. You are using a `NSData` object which represents the content of the file and assign it the request with `setHTTPBody`. This is problematic regarding system memory when the file is *large* and the `NSData` object uses a heap allocated buffer to hold the file's content. You should either use a `NSData` object which uses a memory mapped file or a `NSStream` to represent the file content.
3. You are too vague about the request headers:

   ```
   `[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headersDict];`
   ```

   Request header are important. You should set the Content-Type and possible the Content-Length header.

For "Form-based File Upload", see also [RFC 1867](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt).

Comment: thank you for your advice. But API is set that I have to use PUT request to upload video data. My header: `NSDictionary *headersDict = @{@"Content-Length": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", mySize], @"Content-Type": @"video/mp4", @"Accept": @"application/json", @"Authorization": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", hash]};`

Comment: @petesalt Headers look fine. Please edit your post and include the headers.